# Angular 2 Paper-Input and Form handling

Tags: validation, error-handling, angular, polymer, paper-elements

I would like to use the Ng2 FormBuilder with paper-inputs. I got the bindings and the validation  working:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tr1wYZFyrn4uAzssn5Zs?p=preview

```
 <paper-input ngControl="name"
                   ngDefaultControl
                   required
                   class="col-xs-12"
                   (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(myForm)"
                   error-message="Invalid input!"
                   label="What do you need to do?">  
</paper-input>
```

but how do I link the validation of angular to the "error-message" of Polymer ?
Plus the current solution with the "(keyup.enter)="onSubmit(myForm)" is not ideal as it is submiting even when the form is invalid. How do we link these techno properly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can just use the invalid attribute on the paper-input and set it via angular:

```
[invalid]="name.pristine? false : name.value == undefined? false: !name.valid"
```

I have updated the plnkr.